# `who am i` not working with terminal but working with xterm

Tags: ubuntu, who

When I entered `who am i` on my terminal, there is no output, no matter whether I use bash or zsh.  But with XTerm, `who am i` prints my login info.   Why does this happen?  What difference does zsh or bash or XTerm make?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 currently.

Comment: This question needs to tell answerers what "my terminal" is.  Is it a VT525 connected to a serial port, for example?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1280724#c18

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a terminal-emulator other than xterm?  A while back the people behind (I think) the gnome-terminal decided to "clean-up" the code, and removed the code that makes entries in utmp and wtmp - which who and w uses to identify users - because they felt this feature unnecessery and causing lots of overhead.  Several other terminal-emulators are based on this emulator, and now got the same problem.  xterm though, still makes entries in utmp and wtmp.